# Add UIImage to EKEvent title

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimage

How to I add `UIImage` in iOS event title.

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Title"];
event.startDate ...
event.endDate ...
event.calendar ....
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to Attach files or images on EKEvent. Because there is no place to show Images and All.

Solution : You can Use Image Url with URLSchema.

Example :

```
event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_IMAGE_URL"];
```

Reference : [EKCalendarItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/)

Comment: In that case all the emoji's that I add in Event calendar is set of unicode?